# How I can unpack typing.TypeVarTuple with pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get the type `tuple[A[int], A[int]]` for `b.b`?

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
Ts = typing.TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class A(typing.Generic[T]):
    a: T

class B(typing.Generic[*Ts]):
    b: tuple[*A[Ts]]

b: B[int, int] = B()
typing.reveal_type(b.b) # tuple[A[*tuple[int, int]]] i got
# but i need a tuple[A[int], A[int]]
```

I tried something like `tuple[*(A[T1] for T1 in Ts)]`, but it doesn't work too

UPD:
I want it to be like in c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T a;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct B {
    std::tuple<A<Ts>...> b;
};

int main() {
    B<int, int> b;
    std::cout << typeid(b.b).name() << std::endl;
    // std::__1::tuple<A<int>, A<int>>
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now (Python 3.12) there is no such possibility.** But the issue was created on github [`python/typing`](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1383). And I hope that they will add such an opportunity!

My suggestion:

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar('T')
Ts = typing.TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class A[T]:
    a: T

class B[*Ts]:
    b: tuple[*A[Ts]]

b: B[int, int] = B()
typing.reveal_type(b.b) # tuple[A[int], A[int]]
```

```py
class SerializationWrapper[*Ts]:
    def __init__(
        self, types: *type[Ts],
        additional_encoding_hooks: Callable | None = None,
        additional_decoding_hooks: Callable | None = None,
    ):
        self._types: *type[Ts] = types
        # create stateful en/decoders, register these types, and raise if the types aren't understood or
        # if the types have ambiguous overlap from the perspective of encoding or decoding
        # after the registration of optional hooks

    def encode(obj: *type[Ts]) -> bytes:
        ...

    def decode(bytes) -> Union[*Ts]:
        ...
```